# can't get object variable with "this" property in object function called by setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have another question again. I'm currently working with objects and I'm now in very big problem :D. How can I get object variable with "this" property in object function called by setTimeout() function?

**HTML:**

```
variable value: <span class="log"></span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var logEl = document.getElementsByClassName("log")[0];

var Object = function()
{
    this.variable = "abc";
    setTimeout(this.callVar,1000);
}

Object.prototype.callVar = function()
{
    logEl.innerHTML = this.variable;
}

var obj = new Object();
```

I want to get `variable value: abc`, but I still get `undefined`. How to fix it? setTimeout() must be in code.

Also, I don't want to replace `this.` with `obj.`, just another solution like `parentObj.this.`...any help will be great!

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9vcvbde/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `setTimeout` calls a function, it calls it in the context of the "global" object (`window`).  In JavaScript, `this` is set based on how the function is *called*.

JavaScript has `.bind()` to fix this problem.  Try this:

```
var Object = function()
{
    this.variable = "abc";
    setTimeout(this.callVar.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

This will make sure that when `setTimeout` runs your function, it'll be called in the right "context".

P.S. Don't name a variable `Object`.  JavaScript has a built-in `Object` and replacing that may have unexpected consequences.

Comment: Great! It works in every browser? Also, I've named it "Object" for example :)

Comment: @PDKnight: It won't work in IE 8 or less :)  If you *really* need IE8 support, you can use [Mozilla's Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) or the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I must wait 2 minutes for accepting your answer xD